# Compare 2 xmlNodeList to find difference

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have two xmlNodeLists pulled from the same xmlDocument.
The first, allNodes, contains all the MACHINECONFIGURATIONID nodes in the document and the other, numberedNodes, contains all the MACHINECONFIGURATIONID nodes that have a NUMBER child node.

I want to create a 3rd xmlNodeList, nonNumberedNodes, that contains the nodes in allNodes that are not in numberedNodes.

If these were list(of XmlNode) I would just do:

```
nonNumberedNodes = allNodes.except(numberedNodes)
```

but that doesn't work with xmlNodeList

This is my code so far

```
Sub stripNodesWithoutNumbers()

        Dim xmlFile As New XmlDocument
        Dim xmlFileArray() As String
        Dim numberedNodes As XmlNodeList
        Dim allNodes As XmlNodeList

        Dim x As List(Of XmlNode)

        Dim nonNumberedNodes As XmlNodeList

        xmlFileArray = Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.xml")

        For Each file In xmlFileArray

            xmlFile.Load(file)

            numberedNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID[../NUMBER]")

            allNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID")


        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert those `XmlNodeList` to `List(of XmlNode)` & then use `except`:

```vb
Sub stripNodesWithoutNumbers()
    Dim xmlFile As New XmlDocument
    Dim xmlFileArray() As String
    Dim numberedNodes As List(Of XmlNode)
    Dim allNodes As List(Of XmlNode)

    Dim nonNumberedNodes As List(Of XmlNode)

    xmlFileArray = IO.Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.xml")

    For Each file In xmlFileArray
        xmlFile.Load(file)

        'Cast to XmlNode to allow enumeration to convert to list
        numberedNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID[../NUMBER]").Cast(Of XmlNode).ToList()

        allNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID").Cast(Of XmlNode).ToList()

        nonNumberedNodes = allNodes.Except(numberedNodes).ToList()
    Next
End Sub
```

Then if you need the resulting `nonNumberedNodes` as a `XmlNodeList` you could create a new `XmlDocument` & select from that:

```
Dim resultDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
resultDoc.AppendChild(resultDoc.CreateElement("MACHINES"))
For Each nd In nonNumberedNodes
    resultDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(resultDoc.ImportNode(nd, True))
Next

Dim result As XmlNodeList = resultDoc.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a more elegant Xpath based way to do it.

```
nonNumberedNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID[not (NUMBER)]")
```

This line takes me straight to the list I want, all MACHINECONFIGURATIONID nodes that do not have a number node.  So no need to compare lists or iterate through every single node, which is a performance killer.

```
Sub stripNodesWithoutNumbers()

        Dim xmlFile As New XmlDocument
        Dim xmlFileArray() As String

        Dim nonNumberedNodes As XmlNodeList

        xmlFileArray = Directory.GetFiles(TextBox1.Text, "*.xml")

        For Each file In xmlFileArray

            xmlFile.Load(file)

            nonNumberedNodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("/MACHINECONFIGURATIONVALUES/MACHINECONFIGURATIONID[not (NUMBER)]")

            For Each nonNumberedNode In nonNumberedNodes

                nonNumberedNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(nonNumberedNode)

            Next

            xmlFile.Save(file)

        Next

    End Sub
```